# Picasso stableKey Disk Cache

Tags: caching, picasso

If I specify a `stableKey` for an image request, will it only be used for a memory cache lookup, or will it be persisted in the disk cache? Meaning if the memory cache lookup misses, will the `stableKey` be used to query the disk cache.

Considering [this line](https://github.com/square/picasso/blob/ebce0a70c446b32c6fd7a6f0c5bde595925ecca1/picasso/src/main/java/com/squareup/picasso/BitmapHunter.java#L204) is the last time `key` seems to be referenced, I would say that it is only used for memory cache lookups, but I just want to be sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's only memory cache. Disk cache is managed by OkHttp. It's behaviour cannot be changed because com.squareup.okhttp.Cache is a final class.